# Print corresponding elements from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists `xx` and `yy` where

```
aa = {1, 2, 3, 4}; 
bb = {12, 13, 14, 15}; 
cc = {23, 24, 25, 26}; 
dd = {34, 35, 36, 37};
xx = {aa, bb, cc, dd}; 
yy = Transpose[xx];
```

After `Transpose`,

```
xx = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {12, 13, 14, 15}, {23, 24, 25, 26}, {34, 35, 36, 37}}
yy = {{1, 12, 23, 34}, {2, 13, 24, 35}, {3, 14, 25, 36}, {4, 15, 26, 37}}
```

The goal is to execute a function, `Print` for example, over these two lists by taking from each list one sublist at a time

```
zz = Map[Print[#1, #2] &, {xx, yy}];
```

The object is to get print-out a pair at a time: `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 12, 23, 34}}`, then `{{12, 13, 14, 15}, {2, 1, 3, 24, 35}}`, so on...

Answer (score 4):

```
 MapThread[Print[#1, #2] &, {xx, yy}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

You can `Transpose` the list `{xx, yy}` and `Apply` your function at `Level` `1`:

```
foo @@@ Transpose[{xx, yy}]
```

> ```
> {foo[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 12, 23, 34}], 
>  foo[{12, 13, 14, 15}, {2, 13, 24, 35}], 
>  foo[{23, 24, 25, 26}, {3, 14, 25, 36}], 
>  foo[{34, 35, 36, 37}, {4, 15, 26, 37}]}
> ```

```
Print @@@ Transpose[{xx, yy}]
```

[image]